# ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <label> is not clickable with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on the "All Topics" and "All States" CheckBoxes then search the results. When I run the script, a chrome window opens up in size 1036x674.

If I leave the window alone, I get element click interception errors. If I minimize or maximize the window, my script works fine.

I am using Selenium 3.141.0, chrome 76, chromedriver 76, and python 3.6

```py
chromedriver_path = r"C:\Users\path\to\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
url = "http://www.ncsl.org/research/transportation/autonomous-vehicles-legislative-database.aspx"

topics_xpath = "//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr81355_StateNetDB_UpdatePanel1\"]/div[1]/div[2]/span/label"
states_xpath = "//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr81355_StateNetDB_UpdatePanel1\"]/div[2]/div[2]/span/label"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(30)

elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(topics_xpath)
elem.click()
time.sleep(5)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(states_xpath)
elem.click()
```

But I get this error:

> ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:
>   Element <label for="dnn_ctr81355_StateNetDB_ckBxAllTopics">...</label> is not clickable at point (259, 665).
>   Other element would receive the click:
>   <label for="dnn_ctr81355_StateNetDB_ckBxTopics_0">...</label>
>     (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)

The CheckBox that would be clicked is right below the one I am trying to click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `WebDriverWait` to make sure the element `visibility_of_element_located`, then scroll to `Searchable Database` section, and you can use locator by `xpath`.

Please import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Try the bellow code.

```
chromedriver_path = r"C:\Users\path\to\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
url = "http://www.ncsl.org/research/transportation/autonomous-vehicles-legislative-database.aspx"

topics_xpath = "//div[@class='divTopicsSection1']//span//label[text()='All Topics']"
states_xpath = "//div[@class='divStatesSection1']//span//label[text()='All States']"
dBase_xpath = "//h4[text()='Searchable Database']"
browser.get(url)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, topics_xpath)))
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath(dBase_xpath)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem)

browser.find_element_by_xpath(topics_xpath).click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(states_xpath).click()
```

Comment: They mentioned need to install some libraries.      let me know, how can I installed

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted
```

...implies that the *click* method invoked on the desired element was **intercepted** by some other element.

---

To `click()` on the checkboxes associated with text as **All Topics** and **All States** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.ncsl.org/research/transportation/autonomous-vehicles-legislative-database.aspx")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for$='_StateNetDB_ckBxAllTopics']"))).click()
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for$='_StateNetDB_ckBxAllStates']").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.ncsl.org/research/transportation/autonomous-vehicles-legislative-database.aspx")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(@for, '_StateNetDB_ckBxAllTopics')]"))).click()
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(@for, '_StateNetDB_ckBxAllStates')]").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: checkboxes]

Comment: Thanks I didnt know there was a way to wait until an element is clickable!

Comment: @William Glad to be able to help you out but as you intent to click `element is clickable` is the exact way but not `visibility_of_element_located`