# Selenium - after bootstrap modal test, subsequent test fail with error ElementClickInterceptedError

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

After launching a bootstrap modal and closing it, selenium is not able to find any other element on the page.

Three buttons are shown in screen below. Out of which function of 2 buttons is to launch a bootstrap  modal and close it, and function of third button ( middle one )  is to simply receive a "click".

When tested individually, test for all 3 buttons works well, but when tested collectively it fails.

First time a  test which launch a modal and close it, will pass, but subsequent test fails with ElementClickInterceptedError.

There are sufficient implicit waits in between so that modal can load properly, still issue persist.

**PS** - In case you need to try at your end, follow these steps 1) copy below 2 files 2) install selenium webdriver  using  `npm install selenium-webdriver`  3) change fileName variable in test as per your own folder.

[image: Image 1 - buttons]

[image: Image 2 - modal 1]

**Error Stacktrace**

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:50210/devtools/browser/81f6bc5f-c6f5-4255-9134-5efa67a92bed
>   [13108:12832:0501/100716.495:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)]
>   XXX Init() ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted:
>   Element ... is not clickable at po int (233, 67). Other element
>   would receive the click: ...
>   (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
>       at Object.throwDecodedError (D:\ip300-gk\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:550:15)
>       at parseHttpResponse (D:\ip300-gk\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:565:13)
>       at Executor.execute (D:\ip300-gk\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:491:26)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
>       at async Driver.execute (D:\ip300-gk\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:700:17)
>       at async uitest (D:\ip300-gk\Samples\bootstrap\bs-modal-selenium\uitest.js:34:13) {
>   name: 'ElementClickInterceptedError',

**Test Script**

```
const driver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const assert = require('assert').strict;
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

let fileName = "D:\\ip300-gk\\Samples\\bootstrap\\bs-modal-selenium\\index.html"


function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

(async function uitest() {
        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
        let  element
        try {
            await driver.get(fileName)

            //Launch Modal 1 and close
            await driver.findElement(By.id('launchModalButton')).click()
            await driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 1000} )
            await driver.findElement(By.id('closeButton')).click()


            // middle button click 
             await driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 1000} )
             await driver.findElement(By.id('button')).click()

            //Launch Modal 2 and close
            await driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 1000} )
            await driver.findElement(By.id('launchModalButton_2')).click()
            await driver.manage().setTimeouts( { implicit: 1000} )
            element = await 
            driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('closeButton_2')))
            await element.click()

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {
            await driver.quit();
        }
    }
)()
```

**Bootstrap page**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Selenium </title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">

    <button type="button" id="launchModalButton" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch modal
    </button>

    <button type="button" id="button" class="ml-3 btn btn-primary mt-5">
        Button
    </button>

    <button type="button" id="launchModalButton_2" class="ml-3 btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#exampleModal_2">
        Launch modal 2
    </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal 1</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Modal 1
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="closeButton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="saveChangesButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel_2"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel_2">Modal 2</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Modal 2
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="closeButton_2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                    </button>
                    <button id="saveChangesButton_2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the implicitwait everytime. What you need to wait for is the visibility of the elements before doing the click operations.

There is a `elementIsVisible` method available in the wait condition. I've modified the code to check for the presence of the element and then the visibility of the element before doing the click.

```
(async function uitest() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    let element
    try {
        await driver.get(fileName)

        //Launch Modal 1 and close
        await driver.findElement(By.id('launchModalButton')).click()
        let closeButton1 = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('closeButton')))
        closeButton1 = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(closeButton1))
        await closeButton1.click()

        // middle button click 
        await driver.findElement(By.id('button')).click()

        //Launch Modal 2 and close
        await driver.findElement(By.id('launchModalButton_2')).click()
        let closeButton2 = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('closeButton_2')))
        closeButton2 = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(closeButton2))
        await closeButton2.click()

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
}
)()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[13108:12832:0501/100716.495:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init() ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at po int (233, 67). 
Other element would receive the click: ... (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
```

...implies that the desired element wasn't clickable when you invoked `click()` on it.

---

As you mentioned *test which launch a modal and close it, will pass, but subsequent test fails with ElementClickInterceptedError* essentially means that when you invoked `click()` on the second element <kbd>Button</kbd> at that point of time the [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) containing the element with text as *Launch modal* was still obsecuring the desired element. Hence the *click* on the desired element failed.

### Details

To start with [implicit wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706) may not be effective with modern application built using [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [Angular](https://angular.io/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/), etc.

Effectively you need to [replace implicit wait with explicit wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759).

---

### selenium-webdriver/lib/until

- [elementLocated](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L237): Creates a condition that will loop until an element is found with the given locator.

  ```
  /**
   * Creates a condition that will loop until an element is
   * {@link ./webdriver.WebDriver#findElement found} with the given locator.
   *
   * @param {!(By|Function)} locator The locator to use.
   * @return {!WebElementCondition} The new condition.
   */
  exports.elementLocated = function elementLocated(locator) {
    locator = by.checkedLocator(locator);
    let locatorStr =
        typeof locator === 'function' ? 'by function()' : locator + '';
    return new WebElementCondition('for element to be located ' + locatorStr,
        function(driver) {
      return driver.findElements(locator).then(function(elements) {
        return elements[0];
      });
        });
  };
  ```
- [elementIsVisible](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L301): Creates a condition that will wait for the given element to become visible.

  ```
  /**
   * Creates a condition that will wait for the given element to become visible.
   *
   * @param {!./webdriver.WebElement} element The element to test.
   * @return {!WebElementCondition} The new condition.
   * @see ./webdriver.WebDriver#isDisplayed
   */
  exports.elementIsVisible = function elementIsVisible(element) {
    return new WebElementCondition('until element is visible', function() {
      return element.isDisplayed().then(v => v ? element : null);
    });
  };
  ```

---

### Solution

So your effective code block replacing *implicit wait* with *explicit wait* will be:

```
(async function uitest() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    let  element
    try {
        await driver.get(fileName)

        //Click Launch Modal
        let launchModal = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('launchModalButton')))
        launchModal = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(launchModal))
        await launchModal.click()

        //Close Launch Modal
        let closeModal = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('closeButton')))
        closeModal = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(closeModal))
        await closeModal.click()

        //Click Button
        let button = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('button')))
        button = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(button))
        await button.click()

        //Click Launch Modal 2 and close
        let launchModal2 = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('launchModalButton_2')))
        launchModal2 = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(launchModal2))
        await launchModal2.click()

        //Close Launch Modal 2
        let closeButton2 = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('closeButton_2')))
        closeButton2 = await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(closeButton2))
        await closeButton2.click()          

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
    }
)()
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of related discussions in:

- [ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632563/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-l/57632780#57632780)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741875/selenium-common-exceptions-elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-cl/57749551#57749551)

Answer (score 0):

To bypass ElementNotClickable (this is web-driver logic), you can just use JavaScript click.

```
var element = await driver.findElement(By.id('button'))
driver.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', element)
```