# Selenium click next button yields selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on see more (se flere) on this particular [website](https://coop.no/sortiment/obs-bygg/hageuterom/hytter-boder-og-drivhus) using selenium and python. This is how I am testing it, and i get the following error

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="button button--primary style_loadMore__2rYaL style_button__xicB7"]').click()

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:
```

This is what works:

```
tresults = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="Se flere"]') #flere"]')
for idx, tr in enumerate(tresults):
    #print (tr.text, tr.get_attribute('class'))
    if tr.get_attribute('class') == 'button button--primary style_loadMore__2rYaL style_button__xicB7':
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tr)
        #tr.click()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not click on a Element: ElementClickInterceptedException in Splinter / Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple running code snippet that uses XPATH to find the button Text "Se flere".

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://coop.no/sortiment/obs-bygg/hageuterom/hytter-boder-og- 
drivhus")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Se flere"]')
element.click()
```

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:` that's the error i get

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: This does solve the problem of rendering new elements on the screen. However, when I try to get elements from the product-card, I only get elements that were originally on the website before rendering new elements.

Comment: Your stated problem in above comment is unclear. Selenium is just to interact with the website not to alter its database!

Comment: I understand that Adnan. Let's take an example, if you scroll this webpage, you see a stream of new products. I was hoping to see these when I iterate over the product card ID. Initially, you see 32 products. After the first scroll, I was hoping to see 64.

Comment: When I run this, I see all products all the way down. You just have to wait a few seconds.The last product I see is:
Palmako Nordic+ 1/4 vinduselement
3 790

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

To click on <kbd>Se flere</kbd> you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://coop.no/sortiment/obs-bygg/hageuterom/hytter-boder-og-drivhus')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='CategoryPage']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://coop.no/sortiment/obs-bygg/hageuterom/hytter-boder-og-drivhus')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='CategoryPage']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: coop]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Can not click on a Element: ElementClickInterceptedException in Splinter / Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen/60687304#60687304)
- [ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632563/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-l/57632780#57632780)

Comment: This does not seem to work, and gives the same error.

Comment: @tandem Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Yes, it works. apologies. I had a sleep timer inside the block, and I found this in one of your prior answers. "While using Selenium for automation using time.sleep(secs) without any specific condition to achieve defeats the purpose of automation and should be avoided at any cost. As per the documentation:"

Comment: This does solve the problem of rendering new elements on the screen. However, when I try to get elements from the product-card, I only get elements that were originally on the website before rendering new elements.

Comment: @tandem That all together sounds like a new question. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement please?

Comment: Maybe I can rephrase: With the above code, I'm unable to render the products using selenium. In that aspect, I view it as a same question. but if you think it is different, it's ok

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else I can provide