# ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted Element is not clickable error clicking a radio button using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on the first box (ASN / DSD)

[image]

But I get this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <input type="radio" name="docTypes" ng-model="$ctrl.documentTypes.selected" id="documentType-0" ng-change="$ctrl.onChangeDocumentType()" ng-value="documentType" tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]" aria-invalid="false"> 
is not clickable at point (338, 202). 
Other element would receive the click:
 <label translate-attr="{title: 'fulfillment.documentAction.createNew.modal.documentType.document.title'}" translate-values="{documentName: documentType.name}" for="documentType-0" translate="ASN - DSD" tabindex="0" title="Select ASN - DSD document type">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

I know I have entered the right iframe because it can find the element, just not click on it.
My code is

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="documentType-0"]').click()
```

I saw that DebanjanB answered a similar question on here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen)

I am trying to do his third solution of using execute script. I don't know what CSS selector to use for this model.
The model looks like this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='loadingWhiteBox']"))))
```

My question is what css selector do I need to use on the first line, and then is it just initial xpath I was using on the second line?

Here is the HTML for reference. I get the click intercept error when I try to click on the input section. If use xpath to click on the label tag, it does not error out but also does not click on it. It just moves on to the next section of code without doing anything.

```
<li ng-repeat="documentType in selectDocumentType.documentTypes.displayedList |
orderBy:selectDocumentType.formOrder"> 

<input type="radio" name="docTypes" ng
model="selectDocumentType.documentTypes.selected" id="documentType-0" ng-value="documentType"
tabindex="0" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" value="[object Object]"
aria-invalid="false"> 

<label translate-attr="{title:'fulfillment.documentAction.createNew.modal.documentType.document.title'}" 
translate-values={documentName: documentType.name}" for="documentType-0" translate="ASN - DSD" tabindex="0" title=
"Select ASN - DSD document type"><span>ASN - DSD</span></label> </li>
```

Any suggestions on how to stop having the click intercepted?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <input type="radio" name="docTypes" ng-model="$ctrl.documentTypes.selected" id="documentType-0" ng-change="$ctrl.onChangeDocumentType()" ng-value="documentType" tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" value="[object Object]" aria-invalid="false"> 
is not clickable at point (338, 202). 
Other element would receive the click:
 <label translate-attr="{title: 'fulfillment.documentAction.createNew.modal.documentType.document.title'}" translate-values="{documentName: documentType.name}" for="documentType-0" translate="ASN - DSD" tabindex="0" title="Select ASN - DSD document type">...</label>
```

...implies that the desired element wasn't clickable as some other element obscures it.

---

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='documentType-0']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='documentType-0']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can use the `execute_script()` method as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='documentType-0']"))))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='documentType-0']"))))
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)… Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv/44724688#44724688)
- [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem/44916498#44916498)
- [ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632563/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-l/57632780#57632780)

Comment: when I add this wait into the code,`    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='documentType-0']"))).click()` The program does not error out, but it also does not click the button. Nothing appears to happen on the screen. The program just continues onto the next line. Any ideas on why it would not be clicking the button? @DebanjanB

Comment: @RyanBobber Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: That update using execute script worked!! Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. I have some more issues to troubleshoot so you might see some more questions posted later.

Comment: I just came across this answer, thanks @DebanjanB - literally have been working on it for days. Such a satisfying fix

Comment: Click usin ID, worked perfectly: `WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, pagination_div))).click()`