# How to click on this button element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Here is the full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path = r"C:\Users\H\Desktop\Automated_Tasks\msedgedriver.exe") # Modify the path here...

# Navigate to URL
driver.get("https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/notificationfeed/page")


#accept cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/center/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[1]"))).click()

#click button
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='lia-button lia-button-primary view-more-icon lia-link-ticket-post-action' and @id='viewMoreLink'][contains(@href, 'notificationList')]/span[text()='Show more']"))).click()
```

The following line:

```
button=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "viewMoreLink"))).click()
```

gives an error:

```
File C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:249 in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (476, 1865)
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=109.0.1518.61)
```

Here is the HTML for the button I'm trying to click.

```html
<a onclick="return LITHIUM.EarlyEventCapture(this, 'click', true)" class="lia-button lia-button-primary view-more-icon lia-link-ticket-post-action" data-lia-action-token="gY01pJ4IhqNcqA8Ouq1d20HgZFI9CVTHrEYgxObqxWantjAxFsOxTacdu8LdHjd0" rel="nofollow" id="viewMoreLink" href="https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/notificationfeed/page.notificationlist.notificationlistitems.viewmorelink:viewmore/notificationfeed.lastLoadedTimestamp/1674422253100/notificationfeed.lastViewedTimestamp/1674505573710/container_element/notificationList"><span>Show more</span></a>
```

Here is a picture showing where the desired element is in:

[image]

Comment: hi, can you share  the test url? tnx

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/notificationfeed/page

But you won't be able to access it because it requires one to sign in. Is there another way I can share the source code?.

Comment: more that the source code, a working page for the site under test would be more helpful. I created an account but i do not have any notifications

Comment: Yes you can only get notifications by posting questions, receiving replies etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per the given HTML to click on the element with text as ***Show more*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.lia-button.lia-button-primary.view-more-icon.lia-link-ticket-post-action#viewMoreLink[href$='notificationList'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='lia-button lia-button-primary view-more-icon lia-link-ticket-post-action' and @id='viewMoreLink'][contains(@href, 'notificationList')]/span[text()='Show more']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [*ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted Element is not clickable error clicking a radio button using Selenium and Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62904494/7429447)

Comment: Thanks but I tried both options xpath and css but unfortunately both of them did not work. They returned the same error message I was getting before. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Check if the desired element is within an [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) or within a [**shadowRoot**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242476/7429447)

Comment: Thanks. I've added a picture in the question section showing the hierarchy of the HTML elements. Please see above. I cannot see an Iframe. Also, I'm not too sure about shadowRoot. I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: Would you like me to share more images scrolling up?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.