# How to handle the a tag in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait, linktext

I am facing the problem for below  tag in selenium

HTML Code is :

```
<a data-v-4sa1sads href='#' class='second'>Register</a>
```

I tried using `LinkText`, `PartialLinkText`, `CSS selector`, `Xpath` but it is always showing an error that element click is intercepted.

How to handle this.

Comment: Can you add the surrounding HTML as well? Probably not the <a> element but some other element receives the click event

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Register"))).click();
  ```
- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and `XPATH`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='second' and text()='Register']"))).click();
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Register"))).click()
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.second[href]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : For *python* clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on [**ElementClickInterceptedException**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen/60687304#60687304) in:

- [ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted Element is not clickable error clicking a radio button using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903056/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-is/62904494#62904494)
- [ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632563/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-l/57632780#57632780)