# How to know if a click sent through Selenium python did not work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to catch a error every time I click an icon or an element that is not active.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    element.click()
except:
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    element.click()
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

you can print the exception thrown like this

Answer (score -1):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) won't be able to differentiate between **active** and **inactive** state of an element. But Selenium can distinguish the different states of a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) interms of:

- [presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336)
- [visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)
- [interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)

---

### This usecase

In short `click()` can **fail** majorly because of either:

- [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [ElementClickInterceptedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665001/can-not-click-on-a-element-elementclickinterceptedexception-in-splinter-selen/60687304#60687304)

---

### Solution

You can catch [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715) using the following code block:

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.class#id[attribute='value']").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No such element")
```

You can avoid [ElementClickInterceptedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632563/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-l/57632780#57632780) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154940/how-can-i-make-sure-if-some-html-elements-are-loaded-for-selenium-python/50159359#50159359) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css"))).click()
```