# ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input> is not clickable. Other element would receive the click: <label for="..">

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I know i have seen this Question on StackOverFlow but not i am not able to solve my problem:

Error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" value="" maxlength="25" placeholder=" " class=""> is not clickable at point (446, 716). Other element would receive the click: <label for="Password">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.83)
```

HTML:

```
<input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" value="" maxlength="25" placeholder=" " class="">
```

XPATH AND CSS

```
@FindBy(css = "#Password")
public WebElement password;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='Password']")
public WebElement password;
```

My code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password)).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password)).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
```

Even JAVASCRIPT Click is not working

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

This is happening for all Checkboxes / input fields on this page.
Any solution would be helpful.

Comment: The label tag sort of steals all the events... though you shouldn't really need the click, you can move that to the <label> tag and it will be the same as clicking the input.  (<label> becomes part of the click area for the input) Does sendkeys work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <label> is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632563/elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-click-intercepted-element-l)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" value="" maxlength="25" placeholder=" " class=""> is not clickable at point (446, 716). Other element would receive the click: <label for="Password">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.83)
```

...implies that the *`<input>`* element is not clickable as the *`<label>`* element intercepts the click.

---

### Deep Dive

Presumably the *`<input>`* element is preceeded by *`<label>`* element as follows:

```
<label for="Password" ...>
<input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" value="" maxlength="25" placeholder=" " class="">
```

---

### Solution

In such cases, instead of the *`<input>`* element, you need to target the *`<label>`* element as follows:

- Using *css*:

  ```
  @FindBy(css = "label[for='Password']")
  public WebElement password;
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//label[@for='Password']")
  public WebElement password;
  ```

and finally:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password)).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57632780/7429447)

Comment: This is how HTML is :- 

<div class="content__form-group">
 <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" value="" maxlength="25" placeholder=" " class="">
 <label for="Password">
  password
  <span class="req">*required</span>
 </label>
 <div class="content__form-group__error"> </div>
</div>

but still i am getting error .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using *JavascriptExecutor* instead of *sendKeys* method to send password info

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);          
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("useremail"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='---your email id---';", email);
```